# How to draw a graph with TikZ or pgfplots in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

What is the simplest way to draw graph like this in Latex?
[image]
I tried:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines, color=gray!30, dashed] (-4.9,-4.9) grid (4.9,4.9);
\draw[->,ultra thick] (-8,0)--(8,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-8)--(0,8) node[above]{$y$};

  % First, define nodes
  \draw (0,0) node[circle, inner sep=2pt, fill=black, label={below:{$A(0,0)$}}] (A) {};  
  \draw (5,0) node[circle, inner sep=2pt, fill=black, label={below:{$B(5,0)$}}] (B) {};  
  \draw (2,2) node[circle, inner sep=2pt, fill=black, label={below:{$C(2,2)$}}] (C) {}; 
  \draw (1.5,-2) node[circle, inner sep=2pt, fill=black, label={below:{$D(1.5,-2)$}}] (D) {}; 

  % Draw curved path
  \draw[black]  (A) -- (B);
  \draw[black]  (A) -- (C);
  \draw[black]  (A) -- (D);
  \draw[black]  (C) -- (B);
  \draw[black]  (D) -- (B);
  \draw[red]  (A) .. controls +(-0.1,1.5) and +(0.5,2).. (C);
  \path[->] (A)  edge [bend left] node {aaaa} (C);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But I don't know how to write a code for that.

Comment: How are the curves specified? You can still use `bend left` and `bend right` with different distances or loosenesses. All part of the [curve to keys](https://tikz.dev/library-edges#tikz/curve:to).

Comment: Simpler than `\draw (0,0) node[circle, inner sep=2pt, fill=black, label={below:{$A(0,0)$}}] (A) {};` would be `\node[circle, inner sep=2pt, fill=black, label={below:{$A(0,0)$}}] (A) {};`. Anyways, simplicity is in the eye of the beholder, of course.

Comment: i believe this is one of the rare cases there is no simple solution to draw this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle, inner sep=2pt, fill, label={[inner sep=2pt]left:{$A$}}] (A) at (0,0) {};  
\node[circle, inner sep=2pt, fill, label={[inner sep=2pt]above right:{$B$}}] (B) at (5,0) {};  
\node[circle, inner sep=2pt, fill, label={[inner sep=2pt]above right:{$C$}}] (C) at (2,2) {}; 
\node[circle, inner sep=2pt, fill, label={[inner sep=2pt]below right:{$D$}}] (D) at (1,-1.5) {}; 
\draw (A) -- (B);
\draw (A) -- (C);
\draw (A) -- (D);
\draw (B) -- (C);
\draw (B) -- (D);
\draw (A) to[out=120,  in=170, looseness=2.0] (C);
\draw (A) to[out=100,  in=185, looseness=1.5] (C);
\draw (A) to[out=-10,  in=50,  looseness=2.0] (D);
\draw (A) to[out=-20,  in=80,  looseness=1.5] (D);
\draw (A) to[out=-100, in=160, looseness=1.5] (D);
\draw (A) to[out=-140, in=170, looseness=2.0] (D);
\draw (B) to[out=175,  in=-60, looseness=1.0] (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Connected graph with four nodes]

Comment: Probable easier to use `bend left` and `bend right` than specifying angles manually. -I just did it this way before I noticed that there are no special curves that benefit from `out=..., in=...`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, how can use bend left and bend right?

Comment: e.g. `\draw (A) to[bend left=60, looseness=2.0] (C);`